# Scroll UIViewController to Top when Table Cell Clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

In my main controller, I have a table view with cells the user can click. But currently, if the user scrolled half way to the bottom of the main controller to click a cell, then the page that loads will be half way scrolled as well. How can I make the view of the controller that I segue to scroll to the top when the user clicks the cell? Also, the page that the cells segue to just have a few labels, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Set the table's `contentOffset` to scroll back to the top.  The new offset will be the top `contentInset`, which accounts for any top bars.

You can animate it:

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0 - self.tableView.contentInset.top) animated:YES];
```

... or just set it directly, depending on your need:

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0 - self.tableView.contentInset.top);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Also, my UIViewController does not have any tables, and I want to sets its view to the top when the user views the page. As it currently stands, when the user clicks a cell on the page that does have the table, the page that is segued to is scrolled down to the amount that the user scrolled down to when he clicked a cell.

Comment: View controllers aren't scrollable.  Are you using a page view controller, or a scrollview?  If it's scrolling, it has a contentOffset.  If it's not scrollable, something is affecting the view's frame.  You're going to have to post some code/details to show/explain what the (push?) segue instantiates.

Comment: Your question and comment is not clear at all. In question you are saying that you have a table and in comment you are saying it does not have tables. Its also very confusing on what you are trying to achieve. As @PetahChristian said, you need to post some codes or more details to make things clear.